# How come my PHP Mail function is not working and has no errors?

Tags: php, html

I have a form that users input info and upon submission, an email should be sent and I would also like to redirect to another page which at the moment I am using the form 'action' to do but that is not the main issue. I would like to know why it's not sending for now yet no error shows.

```
        <?php

        include "inc/header.php";



        $error ="";  


        if (isset($_POST['moving']) && !empty($_POST['moving'])){
            if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){

                            //your site secret key
                $secret = '6Lf';
                                //get verify response data
                $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
                $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
                if($responseData->success)

                {


                    $tsize = $_POST['size'];
                    $name = $_POST['omname'];
                    $email = $_POST['ommail'];
                    $phone = $_POST['omphone'];
                    $message = $_POST['ommessage'];
                    $messagetwo = $_POST['tommessage'];


                    $to      = 'test@gmail.com';
                    $subject = 'Moving';


                    $main = '
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <title> Moving</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <h3>Submission from Website - Moving form</h3>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" style="width: 400px; height: auto;">
                    <tr>
                    <th style="width: 200px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left"> Size:</th><td> '.$tutasize.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th style="width: 200px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Name:</th><td> '.$name.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="width: 200px vertical-align: top; text-align: left; background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                    <th style="width: 200px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Email:</th><td> '.$email.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="width: 200px vertical-align: top; text-align: left; background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                    <th style="width: 200px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Phone:</th><td> '.$phone.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="width: 200px vertical-align: top; text-align: left; background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                    <th style="width: 200px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Where From:</th><td> '.$message.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="width: 200px vertical-align: top; text-align: left; background-color: #e0e0e0;">
                    <th style="width: 200px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left">Where to:</th><td> '.$messagetwo.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </body>
                    </html>';

                    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\n";
                    $headers .= 'From: Moving' . "\n" .
                    'Reply-To: test@gmail.com' . "\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                    mail($to, $subject, $main, $headers);

                    echo '<h5 class="feedback-msg" id="hideMe"> Hello <span style="color:#f56464;">'.$name.'</span>, Your order has been received.</h5>';

                    

                }
            }
        }



        ?>
```

Here's my HTML form

```
                        <form action="actin.php" method="POST" id="moving">



                        <div class="paymentWrap">
                            <div class="btn-group paymentBtnGroup btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
                                <label class="btn tsize active">
                                    <div class="method tus"> <span>  S </span></div>
                                    <input type="radio" value="S" class="sradio" name="tsize" checked required=""> 
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn tsize">
                                    <div class="method tum"> <span>  M </span></div>
                                    <input type="radio" value="M" class="mradio" name="tsize" required=""> 
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn tsize">
                                    <div class="method tul"> <span>  L </span></div>
                                    <input type="radio" value="L" class="lradio" name="tsize" required="">
                                </label>

                            </div>        
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group pdt2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="omname" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Name" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row pdt1">
                                <div class="col-md-6"><input type="email" name="ommail" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Email address" required=""></div>

                                <div class="col-md-6 smpt"><input type="phone" name="omphone" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Phone number" required=""></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group pdt1">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" name="ommessage" placeholder="Where from" rows="3" required=""></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group pdt1">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea2" name="tommessage" placeholder="Where to" rows="3" required=""></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lf"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group pdt1">
                            <input type="submit" class="form-submit btn" name="moving" value="Submit" form="moving" placeholder="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Kindly help troubleshoot, I get no error yet no mail is received

Comment: Is the first line of your HTML code correct? You wrote actin.php

Comment: PHP ``mail()`` function does not work on your local machine local host, if thats what your are trying to do.

Comment: I know that and I have tested by uploading on my hosting

Comment: @Pascal yes it where the php code is

Comment: check your junk box

Comment: I have, but nothing yet. I have even tried a friend's email.